# Компиляция gcc, fatal error (gcc -V)

Tags: linux, gcc, solus

Поставил себе Solus (последнюю стабильную версию 1.2.0.5) на рабочий ноутбук.
Начал ставить программы из исходников, и ничего не получается, при запуске любого `./configure` вылетает одна и та же ошибка:

```
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... 
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
```

Полез смотреть лог, и нашел вот это:

```
configure:2517: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
```

Версия gcc (Solus) 6.2.0

Что это такое и как это вылечить?

Comment: Буквально несколько дней назад попадалась схожая ошибка. Этот параметр, `-V`, есть в более старых версиях gcc, но в новых - он отсутствует. Например в 4.4.7 он ещё есть (`-V <version>             Run gcc version number <version>, if installed`), а в 4.8.5 его уже нет. Возможно вам поможет использование gcc более старой версии.